# Realm not found (ACS, ADDS, AD FS)

Tags: azure, active-directory, acs, adfs, federated-identity

i am playing around with the azure free triel and followed this tutorial (http://haishibai.blogspot.de/2012/11/complete-walkthrough-setting-up-adfs-20.html) titled "Setting up a ADFS 2.0 Server on Windows Azure IaaS and Configuring it as an Identity Provider in Windows Azure ACS".

When it comes to starting the MVC Web Application i am confronted with the following in the browser:

> An error occurred while processing your request. HTTP Error Code:     400
>   Message:  ACS20000: An error occurred while processing a WS-Federation
>   sign-in request. Inner Message:   ACS50001: Relying party with realm
>   'https://ACS-NAMESPACE.accesscontrol.windows.net/' was not found. Trace ID:
>     64827ce0-71d2-49bf-996c-aadf23779fc7 Timestamp:     2012-12-13 22:17:12Z

Where ACS-NAMESPACE is the name of my ACS namespace.

I can say that i followed the steps given in the tutorial correctly, as i went through it several times. However, i can not figure our what the problem with my realm specification is.

Note: When i am configuring google or windows live as identity providers in ACS and not ADFS everything works.

Thanks, 
David

Comment: You've clearly made a mistake if you're seeing this error. The relying party realm configured at ACS should not be your ACS namespace, but instead should be the URI of the relying party website.

Comment: That's right, please see my comment to the answer below.

Comment: Which website gave you the error - was it the ad server, or the azure access control site?

Answer (score 1):

The realm should be the URL of your MVC Web Application not the ACS URL - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185906.aspx#BKMK_1 for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks. i have checked my configuration but could not figure out where the heck the realm is set to this value. In the ACS portal the url of the realm is localhost:4314 as is the return url. In the web.config (pastebin.com/d3rv8Xa2) it is the same. So, is there another way to set the realm?

Comment: That's everywhere the realm could be set. Are you running on localhost:4314 for debugging?

Comment: Yes, i've tried some other ports without getting another result. The funny part is: When ACS portal and Web.config have the same realm- value (like http://localhost:4314/) i am confronted with the exact same error as above. When they have different values like ACS portal with http://localhost:4314/ and Web.config with http://localhost:7777/ i get the same error message like above but not with the message 'https://ACS-NAMESPACE.accesscontrol.windows.net/ was not found' but with 'http://localhost:7777/ was not found - the realm url in my web.config. But the app runs on this port.

Answer (score 1):

If the realm is not found on ACS it is probably incorrectly configured as a ServicePrincipal on the WAAD Management service using powershell.

Please check the following and make sure you are configuring the correct ACS Namespace (and not the WAAD Tenant Name):

See if it is listed correctly by using

> Get-MsolServicePrincipal

To create another one use following cmds:

> $replyUrl = New-MsolServicePrincipalAddresses -Address "https://ACSNAMESPACE.accesscontrol.windows.net/"
>   New-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalNames @("https://ACSNAMESPACE.accesscontrol.windows
>   .net/") -DisplayName "ACSNAMESPACE Namespace" -Addresses $replyUrl